# Should I "refactor" my answer into separate answers? If yes, how?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

For this question [NSR Certificate Verification](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/94456/3192), I suggested in the comments that my older answer here [If I don't have a relieving letter from a job, should I exclude those years worked from my total experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/80174/3192) would be helpful<sup>1</sup>.

However, I read the older question (which I had edited too) and my answer again, and realized in hindsight that I might have screwed up the editing to an extent. In particular, one line near the end of the linked question "Could this action get me blacklisted in NASSCOM?" has been covered by about 1/3rd of the answer.

I now think that although the topics of "alternatives to relieving letter for proving work experience" and "background verification by NSR" are closely related, it would be better from our site's perspective to not bundle those two together into one post.

With this refactoring, marking questions as duplicates would be more effective, as it would lead users to their answers sooner. This is particularly important in case of new users, who might be confused as to why they are told their question on NSR verification has answers elsewhere, but most of that question is focussed on something else, and the answer greets them with several paragraphs about alternatives to relieving letter and how to handle the company lowballing you on the salary offered.

Is this kind of "refactoring" allowed here? If yes, how should I go about extracting the NSR verification part out of that answer? If no, does anyone else see the above as an issue, and if so, what alternatives do we have to fix it?

PS: I am also wondering if "alternatives to relieving letter" should be further split apart from "how to deal with company lowballing you due to lack of work experience proof" for reasons similar to above.

---

<sup>1</sup> I could not cast a duplicate close vote because I had already retracted my wrong close vote.

Comment: this question is on hold

Comment: @Kilisi It was on hold exactly because of the duplicate I linked to. I am trying to figure out a way to fix the issue, because it is not exactly a duplicate. The linked question is mainly concerned with a different topic, and just happens to cover this issue as a "by the way" sideshow.